# how to change index.html/php into index.myname?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is it possible to change Extension of file without affecting output..

for example : http://www.cox.com/myconnection/home.cox

From the above URL : File Extension .cox . like this

Help me soon.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're using `Apache` as your server you might want to take a look at [`mod_rewrite`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: This could be achieved with .htaccess - javascript too but js seems to be more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give you a full answer, I would need more information, such as the file mime type you're trying to change and your server environment.

With Apache, you can assign file extensions to a mime type. For example, to make '*.cox' files be interpreted as PHP files on Apache, simply add the following rule either in your httpd.conf or in an .htaccess file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .cox
```

Now Apache will treat '*.cox' files as PHP files and let the PHP engine process them. For different mime-types, just change the mime type - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help. Was the answer clear and useful?

Comment: Yes . It tried in localhost, it works great. now have to check on live